# How to confirm a validation in a Vaadin Binder

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

Let's say I have the following `Binder` validation on the Bean bankAccount:

```
binder.withValidator(bankAccount ->
{
    if(!bankAccount.hasEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal())
         return false;
    return confirmCustomerWillAcceptATMTransactionFee();
}, "Cannot withdraw money");
```

How can I confirm that the customer will accept the fee before proceeding? The only dialogs I can see that return user feedback have a callback method therefore I can't seem to figure out how to do this in a Binder?

Comment: How about adding one mode check-box to your form, which the user must tick before continuing? You know, the usual "I have read and agreed with the license terms...." which (mostly) everyone ticks without reading anything. Alternatively create your own window implementation, with a callback that accepts a `true/false` value, and obviously if `true`, then executes the transaction.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is missing some information so I filled in the gaps as best as I could.

You can find below a possible solution with a modal window and a callback, based on an additional validator checking a "*virtual*" fee confirmation, in the form of a boolean field.

The save button is disabled util the user enters the correct and complete information in the form, and the only "*error*" is not accepting the fee yet (you can refrain from adding the binder status `Label` to the form if you don't want to see it, but the effect is still the same)

**Bean:**

```java
// simple pojo for binding
public class BankAccount {
    private int currentAmount;

    public BankAccount(Integer currentAmount) {
        this.currentAmount = currentAmount;
    }

    public Integer getCurrentAmount() {
        return currentAmount;
    }

    public boolean hasEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal(Integer withdrawalAmount) {
        return currentAmount >= withdrawalAmount;
    }
}
```

**Confirmation window:**

```java
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

// confirmation window
public class ConfirmationWindow {
    private Integer value;

    public ConfirmationWindow(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void showModal(Consumer<Boolean> resultCallback) {
        Window window = new Window("Confirm transaction");
        window.setContent(
                new VerticalLayout(
                        new Label("Your account will be charged with " + (value / 100) + " for this transaction, are you sure you want to continue?"),
                        new HorizontalLayout(
                                new Button("Ok", event -> {
                                    resultCallback.accept(true);
                                    window.close();
                                }),
                                new Button("Cancel", event -> {
                                    resultCallback.accept(false);
                                    window.close();
                                })
                        )
                )
        );
        window.setModal(true);
        getUI().addWindow(window);
    }
}
```

**Form:**

```java
import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.data.converter.StringToIntegerConverter;
import com.vaadin.ui.*;

public class TransactionForm extends FormLayout {

    private static final String FEE_ACCEPTED_MESSAGE = "Press the save button to view the transaction fee and confirm";

    // initial withdrawal mount
    private Integer value = 0;
    // used to make binder "invalid" until confirmation dialog is closed with "Ok"
    private Boolean customerAcceptedAtmFee = false;

    public TransactionForm() {
        // some existing bean (eg, loaded from DB for editing)
        BankAccount bean = new BankAccount(1000);

        // form components
        TextField currentAmount = new TextField("Available");
        TextField withdrawalAmount = new TextField("Withdraw");

        // binder setup
        Binder<BankAccount> accountBinder = new Binder<>(BankAccount.class);
        Label statusLabel = new Label();
        accountBinder.setStatusLabel(statusLabel);

        // consider valid only if the client has also accepted to pay the fee
        accountBinder.withValidator(bankAccount -> customerAcceptedAtmFee, FEE_ACCEPTED_MESSAGE);

        // current amount
        accountBinder.forField(currentAmount)
                .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter("Whatever"))
                .bind(BankAccount::getCurrentAmount, null);

        // withdrawal amount
        accountBinder.forField(withdrawalAmount)
                .withConverter(new StringToIntegerConverter("Please enter a valid value"))
                .withValidator(bean::hasEnoughMoneyForWithdrawal, "Not enough money")
                .withValidator(value -> value > 0, "Please select a value greater than 0")
                .asRequired("Please select withdrawal amount")
                .bind(bankAccount -> TransactionForm.this.value, (bankAccount, value) -> TransactionForm.this.value = value);

        // bind to bean
        accountBinder.setBean(bean);

        // show the modal and assign the call-back logic
        Button saveButton = new Button("Save", event -> new ConfirmationWindow(this, Integer.valueOf(withdrawalAmount.getValue())).showModal(value -> {
            // whether the client selected yes or no
            customerAcceptedAtmFee = value;

            // if all data selected, and client pressed "Ok", then execute the transaction
            if (accountBinder.validate().isOk()) {
                removeAllComponents();
                addComponent(new Label("Transaction executed"));
            }
        }));

        // disable the save button by default and enable it if
        // the only validation error is the fact that the use has not yet accepted the fee
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        accountBinder.addStatusChangeListener(event -> {
            saveButton.setEnabled(accountBinder.getStatusLabel().get().getValue().equals(FEE_ACCEPTED_MESSAGE));
        });

        // add fields to the UI
        addComponents(currentAmount, withdrawalAmount, statusLabel, saveButton);
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: binder with confirmation window]

Comment: Usage of accountBinder.addStatusChangeListener is good idea. You could also ask from binder right there if status is valid and thus you wouldn't need to use message label as flag.

Comment: @JukkaNikki unfortunately it seems you can't, because my understanding from his comment to your answer is that he wants to commit the bean changes only after agreeing to the fee, so until `Yes` i pressed, the binder should be always 'invalid'. This is why I used that field+validator, and checked the status label for that specific messge.

Comment: Field + validator is fine design. And you might be right. When there is need for confirming transaction twice (first save, then ok) there might not be any shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Please see lifecycle of binder validation.

Binder documentation at https://vaadin.com/api/8.3.2/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html says "Bean level validators can be added using the withValidator(Validator) method and will be run on the bound bean once it has been updated from the values of the bound fields. Bean level validators are also run as part of writeBean(Object) and writeBeanIfValid(Object) if all field level validators pass.".

You might not want it to be asked from user every time binder changes if he/she accepts transaction fee.

I'd consider to use dialog to ask confirmation after writeBeanIfValid succeeds https://vaadin.com/api/8.3.2/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html#writeBeanIfValid-BEAN-

Note that this idea is only applicable if you use readBean https://vaadin.com/api/8.3.2/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html#readBean-BEAN- instead of setBean, meaning that you use buffered mode (binder doesn't write changes directly to bean) instead of unbuffered mode (changes written directly to bean).

Comment: The problem is a confirmation requires a callback method which is outside of the binder, and hence the binder completes without knowing if the answer was a yes or no to complete the transaction.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier could you please share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to illustrate your full flow? As it stands now, we have to make some assumptions/guesses and it's difficult to come up with a solution.